# Erase functionality not working in Custom SurfaceView Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, erase

I have a custom surfaceView which will paint the surface based on Touch event. When i draw something on this view it is working fine. But when i tried to erase the paint, nothing got erased. Please find the sample code snippet below:

```
public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView {
private static final String TAG = "FreeHandDrawing";
public static Canvas mCanvas;
SurfaceHolder holder;
private static Path path;
private Paint paint;
private ArrayList<Path> pathArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private boolean freeHandMode;

public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    freeHandMode = false;
    path = new Path();
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    this.setZOrderOnTop(true);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(0xFF22FF11);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(8);

}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if(freeHandMode) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            Log.d("Action", "Placed");
            path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());

        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

            Log.d("Action", "Moved");
            path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            pathArrayList.add(path);

        }

        mCanvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        if (mCanvas != null) {
            if (pathArrayList.size() > 0) {

                mCanvas.drawPath(pathArrayList.get(pathArrayList.size() - 1), paint);

            }
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(mCanvas);

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Canvas is NULL");
        }
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Log.d(TAG, "On draw called");

}

public void eraseDrawing() {
    pathArrayList.clear();
    invalidate();
}

public void drawEnableDisable(boolean mode) {
    freeHandMode = mode;
  }
}
```

What is the problem with the code above ?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your drawing code in the `onDraw` method

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // In case you want to delete/erase when path array/list is cleared.
    if (pathArrayList.size() == 0) {
        canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
    }
    // In case, you want to draw all paths also in onDraw
    for(Path path : pathArrayList) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

When you clear the Path Array(list) and then upon calling invalidate(), onDraw gets triggered.

Note: You're supposed to call invalidate() at the end of onTouchEvent() to tell the system to update the screen. Calling invalidate() will get the framework to eventually call onDraw().

Also you **should NOT** use `canvas` obtained by `lockCanvas` as it will not be hardware accelerated. Instead you should use the canvas passed as an argument to onDraw() itself.

You can choose to make the system a bit smart by not having to draw the pull list of paths every frame and instead handle erases/redraws etc by using special flags. And otherwise just render the latest path generated by the most recent call to onTouchEvent().

Comment: Thanks Bajaj for your reply. Does it affect the performance if i try to draw in onTocuhEvent ?. Also the code you given above seems doesn't have any impact on draw or erase, its not working.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling invalidate() on the view?

And yes onDraw() is called by the framework in the during rendering, if the view has been invalidated. It might as well be in a different thread (rendering thread), so doing complex operations in onTouchEvent (which gets called from the UI/main thread) is not advisable.

Comment: onDraw method not getting triggered, i have checked the defined log inside onDraw, but no such Logs. Am i missing something ?